# how to add specific time to current time using DateAdd?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to add some tie like 2.30 hrs to current time but its not working as desired 
here is my function

```
create FUNCTION Testingdate()
        RETURNS datetime
        AS
        BEGIN
            declare @Time int = 02
            declare @DateNow datetime=getdate()
            return dateadd(HOUR,@Days,@DateNow)
        END
```

and when I execute the command

```
select dbo.GoAdminDate() as x
```

and answer is:

2013-12-12 13:19:17.913

It is adding days to current date but not time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add hours and minutes separately

```
dateadd(MINUTE, 30, dateadd(HOUR, 2, @dateyouaddto))
```

Comment: return dateadd(MINUTE, dateadd(HOUR,@DateNow,@time),30)    i tried this but its showing error"Argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 2 of dateadd function.
"

Comment: Very sorry, wrong order of parameters, I was writing from memory. Try now.

Comment: okay ill try that and one more.. if i wanna add like 1 day and 2 and half hours to current date  dateadd(MINUTE, dateadd(HOUR,dateadd(DD,@days,@DateNow),@time),30) will this query work or i have just reversed every thing

Comment: `dateadd(MINUTE, 30, dateadd(HOUR, 2, dateadd(DAY, @days,@DateNow)))`. The order in which you're adding is not relevant.